# How can I find the difference of two sums based on the Dates and the Same PK Individualid number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find duplicate individualIDs and determine which IndividualIDs have improved.
For example, for each IndividualID I need the sum of C_Q1, C_Q2, C_Q3, C_Q4, C_Q5 and based on the date and 1 being the most improvement and 5 being the least improvement, count that IndividualID if the 2nd sum is a lower number than the first number and would determine which is the 1st number by the UpdateDate being the earliest date and the 2nd number is for the later date.
For Anxiety_Arr, Hyper_Arr, Exagg_Arr, Anxiety_Dep, Hyper_Dep, Exagg_Dep, 1 is the least improvement and 0 is the most improvement, so after summing those it would be counted if the second sum is less than the first sum.

[image]

This is the code to get the sums I need but then need help to find out how to compare the 1st and 2nd numbers for each individualID and the count of individuals who have the 2nd sum being lower than the 1st sum.

```
    select distinct
             IND.Individuals_IndividualID 
       ,     C.ATQChild_IndividualID
       ,     ANS.ANS_IndividualID
       ,     C.UpdateDate as ATQChild_UpdateDate
       ,     ANS.UpdateDate as ANS_UpdateDate
       ,     c.q1_c as C_Q1
       ,     c.q2_c as C_Q2
       ,     c.q3_c as C_Q3
       ,     c.q4_c as C_Q4
       ,     c.q5_c as C_Q5
       ,     Sum(isnull(cast(Q1_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(Q2_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(Q3_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(Q4_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(Q5_c as int),0)) as ChildSum
       ,     Sum(isnull(cast(anxiety_arr as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(hyper_arr as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(exagg_arr as int),0)) as ANS_ArrSum
       ,     Sum(isnull(cast(anxiety_dep as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(hyper_dep as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(exagg_dep as int),0)) as ANS_DepSum
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[anxiety_arr])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Anxiety_Arr
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[hyper_arr])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Hyper_Arr
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[exagg_arr])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Exagg_Arr
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[anxiety_dep])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Anxiety_Dep
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[hyper_dep])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Hyper_Dep
        ,   CASE WHEN (ANS.[exagg_dep])='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Exagg_Dep 
from DBO.tb_cdcp_individuals ind
left join DBO.tb_cdcp_ATQChild c on c.[tb_cdcp_individuals] = ind.[tb_cdcp_individuals]
left join DBO.tb_cdcp_ans_checklist ANS on ans.[tb_cdcp_individuals] = ind.[tb_cdcp_individuals]
group by IND.tb_cdcp_individuals,C.[tb_cdcp_individuals],ANS.[tb_cdcp_individuals],C.UpdateDate,ANS.UpdateDate    
       ,     c.q1_c 
       ,     c.q2_c 
       ,     c.q3_c 
       ,     c.q4_c
       ,     c.q5_c 
       ,     ANS.Anxiety_Arr
       ,     ANS.hyper_arr
       ,     ANS.exagg_arr
       ,     ANS.Anxiety_Dep
       ,     ANS.Hyper_Dep
       ,     ANS.Exagg_Dep
```

Comment: Surely, you can simplify the data and the query to more precisely illustrate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lag/lead functions to compare consecutive records for an ID. For example, for the following sample (Assuming that the table name is temp):

ID    Date   CQ1To5

1   1/1/2019    10

1   1/2/2019     5

```
select *,lag(CQ1To5,1) Over(Partition by ID Order by Date) as lag_date,
Case when lag(CQ1To5,1) Over(Partition by ID Order by Date) is NULL then 0
when lag(CQ1To5,1) Over(Partition by ID Order by Date)<CQ1To5 then 1 else 0 end as Flag from temp
```

This should give you the following output:

ID    Date   CQ1To5  Lag_date   Flag

1   1/1/2019    10     5         1

1   1/2/2019     5    NULL       0

Your flag value should be 1 wherever the next record of the ID is an improvement. You can modify this query to fit your specific needs. Hope this helps.

Note: CQ1to5 indicates the sum of all the 5 fields you mentioned

You can do the same using joins and row number:

```
select *,Row_number() Over(Partition by ID Order by Date) as rownum
into #temp1
from #temp

select a.*,b.CQ1to5,case when a.CQ1to5<b.CQ1to5 then 1 else 0 end as flag
into #temp2
from #temp1 a left join #temp1 b on a.id=b.id and a.rownum=b.rownum+1

select *,row_number() over(Partition by ID,flag order by Date) as rownum1
into #temp3
from #temp2

UPDATE #temp3
SET flag=0
where flag=1 and rownum1>1
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to use the Lag function, "'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, but I must not have the version needed to use the lag function. Is there something else similar to the lag function that I can use?

Comment: LAG or LEAD functions are available from SQL Server 2012 onwards. I have SQL Server 2008

Comment: I have added another possible solution using joins to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: This query is almost doing what I need it to, except do you know how I can get it so that each individual only has one 1? I modified the query because it wasnt always counting a 1 when the last number was lower than the one before it. I changed a.CQ1to5=b.CQ1to5 to a.CQ1to5<b.CQ1to5 but that creates multiple 1s for each individual.

Comment: Do you want just the first instance of 1 to be left as 1 and the remaining changed to 0? Or do you just want to check the first instance of an individual?

Comment: Ideally, I want to check each instance of the individual and any time the number gets lower from the one before it it would get a 1, but only just one 1 for each individual, so probably by putting 0s after it finds that first 1 should work.

Comment: I have added an edit to take care of your request. There are probably much better/optimal ways to do this, but this should give what you need.

Comment: It now gives me a count of 1 for each individual. I just have one more thing - can the ANS sums be incorporated into the query or would i need to create a separate query? It needs to include the ANS fields also.

Comment: You can incorporate it into the same query as a different field. Are you looking for a similar calculation for the ANS fields as well?

Comment: Yes it needs the same calculation. The numbers are just different, so instead of 1 through 5, its 1 and 0 and the 0 is what would be the lower number that gets a count of 1

Comment: The different is that I need to compare the Anxiety_Arr, Hyper_Arr, Exagg_Arr to the  Anxiety_Dep, Hyper_Dep, Exagg_Dep. So if the individual has a lower number for the Departures (Anxiety_Dep, Hyper_Dep, Exagg_Dep) then the arrivals, then it gets a 1.